# Type and change a div innerhtml immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a function where I type something in input it change immediately the innerhtml of `div` nearby.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="span_data" placeholder="Example input">
<div id="round" style="border:1px solid gray; width:40px; height:40px;float: right; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #cc66ff;align-items: center;justify-content: center;display: flex;">+</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).on('change', '#span_data', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#span_data').val();
    $('#round').html(data);
});
```

The innerhtml change only when I click outside the input not when I type.

Where have I do wrong ? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvn7wrg4/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `input` not `change`

```js
$(document).on('input', '#span_data', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#span_data').val();
  console.log(data);
  $('#round').html(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="span_data" placeholder="Example input">



<div id="round" style="border:1px solid gray; width:40px; height:40px;float: right; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #cc66ff;align-items: center;justify-content: center;display: flex;">+</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: `input` would be better than `keyup`.

Comment: Check this out.
MDN-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event
W3-https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp
It comes under form events in W3

Answer (score 3):

Use `input` instead of `change`

Jquery

```
 $(document).on('input', '#span_data', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#span_data').val();
    $('#round').html(data);
});
```

Try it on JsFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mp1z5kw6/)

Answer (score 2):

The selector you're targeting in your event listener is the document. But what you're really trying to listen to is the input field specifically. You also mention wanting the event to trigger as you type, so the keyup event is probably what you're looking for.

This $('here') is the selector. You used it correctly on the #round element so you get the idea.

```
 $('#span_data').keyup(function(){
        var inputValue = $('#span_data').val();
    $('#round').html(inputValue);
 });
```

Below is a second way of writing the event listener using the 'on' method you used above. Either one works. I prefer the former for the brevity.

```
 $('#span_data').on('keyup', function(){
        var inputValue = $('#span_data').val();
    $('#round').html(inputValue);
 });
```

Keyup jquery doc link:
https://api.jquery.com/keyup/